# How to move around a UI element during run-time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I require to move around a button UI element during runtime via code. How can I accomplish this?

The button UI element has these following properties:
Layout
- Width
- Height
- Left
- Top
- Margin (Left, Right, Top, Bottom)

I require to change is the Layout->Left and Layout->Right during runtime.
When I googled for it, I mostly found information on altering the Margin, and not the Left and Top values. Please guide me. I expect it's a standard question, unfortunately I have been unable to find the answer to it.

Comment: It is unclear what are the "left and "top" properties to you. Can you show the XAML and tell exactly what you're trying to change? Could it be `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left`?

Comment: `<Button x:Name="buttonPlayTrailer" Content="Button" Canvas.Left="552" Canvas.Top="202" />` Indeed it is Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` are attached properties, they are set in a slightly different way than ordinary properties.

The "standard" way is to use the `.SetValue` method:

```
buttonPlayTrailer.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 500);
```

Another way is to use the `Canvas.SetLeft` and `Canvas.SetTop` methods (it will have the exact same result, it's just more convenient):

```
Canvas.SetLeft(buttonPlayTrailer, 500);
```

Comment: answered when I was typing. But yours is more complete. zo +1 :p

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MoveButton(int leftOffset,int topoffset)
{
   Canvas.SetLeft(buttonPlayTrailer,leftOffset);
   Canvas.SetTop(buttonPlayTrailer,topoffset);
}
```

something like that?

Comment: Actually this solution will work only from within button event callback. I needed to reposition the button based upon some other parameters in the app. KooKiz's solution is more complete. Thanks..

Comment: I Agree. I was not aware that is can only be done in a button event?! using SetValue works just as well